# iOS App store location

Tags: ios, localization

I'm developing an iOS app and want it to be available in the dutch app store after I distribute it.
How can I define this in my xcode project?

My 'localization native development region' is set to 'en'. I can't change this to 'nl'. (So this is not the place to define it right??.

In the project 'info' 'Locatiozations' area of my project I have 'English' defined. Does it mean that when I add the dutch localization to it the app will be available in both Enlish and Dutch store? Do I have to remove the English localization to be sure the app will only available in the dutch store?

I need some help in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your app available on the dutch store, you have to change it in itunes connect. Nothing to do on the code base.

The languages you have in your project will be automatically picked up by iOS depending on the language of the user.

So if you both have english and dutch, dutch languages phones user will see an app in dutch, an english languages phones will see it in english.
Others will default to english.